# Flutter: Text fontSize does not scale

Tags: flutter

This is the same app, on 2 different devices. The layout seems to scale just fine, but the font size does not. I have no clue what could be the cause or where to start looking. The first is on a Pixel 2 and looks normal, the second is on a Galaxy A7 2018 and the text is off scale.

### [image]

[image]

Comment: My assumption is that Galaxy S7 has the "elderly mode" enabled - all text is enlarged on the device by default. Do you think that's the case?

Comment: @George I thought so too, gonna take a look in the settings, but I see it happening on a few devices, and I don't think it is because of that setting. Seems like the whole UI is just scaled too big somehow

Comment: @George Indeed I was wrong, it is exactly that option!

Comment: Haha well, I actually encountered similar behavior when I borrowed a phone to test my app on. Apparently, people with farsightedness use that setting to read text easier. You might want to consider adjusting your UI for that group of people, since accessibility does matter.

Answer (score 1):

George in the comments was right, it was an option in android to scale fonts that caused this effect. I had to use the code (from [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22480#issuecomment-425720215)) below to set the app-wide `textScaleFactor` back to 1.0.

```
MaterialApp(
      builder: (context, child) {
        return MediaQuery(
          child: child,
          data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
        );
      },
)
```